# Rabbitmq: Multiple Servers and Database updation issue using JRuby?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, jruby

I am new to RabbitMQ fanout exchange. I have used it to update and fetch large amount of records in database.I have a 4 servers up and running.

I am able to fetch and update records from multiple servers but I am facing following  issue:

When I call API, Lets consider there are 2000 records and I am fetching in batch of 100.

Suppose I want change status **created** to **active**.
what happens is first server taking first 100 records and I am updating a status from **created** to **active** for each record.

Parallelly second, third and fourth server fetching 100 records each.
When other servers taking same entry it is not waiting to update and save record process of first server.

Other 3 server getting status as **created** only because it does not wait to update records.

Example:

```
id: 1,  status: created
id: 2,  status: created
```

1. First server(Checks if status is created and it's true) - Fetched id 1 (updating status to active > save > show on UI)

At the same time

2nd server taking same record check status for id-1 and
getting status is **created** because first server is not finished with id-1 yet.

thats why it is again fetching same record (id 1 > Fetch records -> updating status > save > show on UI)

Please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I think the term you should be using here is "worker" instead of "server", as in this context RabbitMQ takes the role of the server.

Comment: I have aws servers and they are pointing to different queue.

Comment: It's all about context. Obviously your code is running on some kind of "server", but I'm talking about the client-server role.

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting yourself here by using the fanout. If you want to broadcast requests to all workers simultaneously, that's what fanout can do, but if you want the workers to pool together and process each task once, they can all service a single queue.

Try attaching all the workers to a single queue, and inject into that queue as necessary. Each worker will pull out jobs from the queue, and only one worker will be assigned to each job.

The fanout model is used for situations where all workers must be notified of something, like a configuration change, a message they might be interested in, etc.